# openpyxl in Python delete_rows function breaks the merged cell

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I use openpyxl 2.6.0 in Python3 (with Django).

I want to manipulate my excel skelton sheet (some cells are merged) to delete a row. But after deleting the row, the merged cells are no longer merged.

I want to keep the merged cells even if some rows are deleted.

Code and excel sample is below.

```
def excelsample(request):

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static', 'excel', 'sample.xlsx'))

    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    sheet.delete_rows(6) # delete 6th row

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{fn}"'.format(fn=urllib.parse.quote("excelsample.xlsx"))

    wb.save(response)

    return response
```

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1139/merged-cells-dont-move-correctly-when-rows) on the openpyxl bug tracker covering this.  It has been marked as invalid.

The basic problem is that for this to work, all merged cell ranges would need to be checked and updated after the row delete.  There are several complex/difficult issues of similar nature that have been deemed to be of minimal value and thus have not been implemented.

You could do this yourself if needed.  There is an attribute (`merged_cells`) on the worksheet that you could update after the row delete.

#### Code:

```
def delete_row_with_merged_ranges(sheet, idx):
    sheet.delete_rows(idx)
    for mcr in sheet.merged_cells:
        if idx < mcr.min_row:
            mcr.shift(row_shift=-1)
        elif idx <= mcr.max_row:
            mcr.shrink(bottom=1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('csvfile.xlsx')

sheet = wb['Sheet2']
delete_row_with_merged_ranges(sheet, 6)

wb.save('csvfile2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Related answer for deleting columns within a merged cell range: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58412906/how-to-delete-columns-of-excel-with-openpyxl-without-changing-the-merged-cells/69705029#69705029

Answer (score 0):

For openpyxl 3.04 and Python 3.8.5 the code in Stephen Rauch's answer works only if we change `<` to `<=` in the elif clause:

```
def delete_row_with_merged_ranges(sheet, idx):
    sheet.delete_rows(idx)
    for mcr in sheet.merged_cells:
        if idx < mcr.min_row:
            mcr.shift(row_shift=-1)
        elif idx < mcr.max_row:
            mcr.shrink(bottom=1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why have you copied the solution from the answer posted earlier. It would be enough to comment on that answer to say: "This solution works with openpyxl 3.04 python 3.8.5"

Comment: it's not just a copy it is a correction
check line# 6  it should be < instead of <=

Comment: I still think that it would have been better to add a comment to the original answer. But thanks for the contribution. I changed your answer to highlight the difference. As it will be approved, you'll see it. If it turns out that your version works well with all the Python/openpyxl versions or for different versions we need different solutions we should correct that answer. It will be easier to find the answer.

Comment: I tested this answer vs Stephen's answer with openpyxl 3.0.9 and python 3.9.5. This answer gave incorrect results, whereas Stephen's answer gave the correct results. Logically, you would want to shrink the merged cell range if `idx == mcr.max_row`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment to the Stephen Rauch answer, because I have not enough reputation to comment.

if you want to delete many rows, the code is here:

```
    def delete_rows(self, idx: int, amount: int = 1):
        self.sheet.delete_rows(idx, amount)
        merged_cells = [_ for _ in self.sheet.merged_cells.ranges]
        for index, mcr in enumerate(merged_cells):
            if idx < mcr.min_row:
                if idx + amount - 1 >= mcr.min_row:
                    mcr.shrink(top=idx + amount - mcr.min_row)
                    if mcr.min_row > mcr.max_row:
                        self.sheet.merged_cells.ranges.remove(mcr)
                        continue
                mcr.shift(row_shift=-amount)
            elif idx <= mcr.max_row:
                mcr.shrink(bottom=min(mcr.max_row - idx + 1, amount))
            if mcr.min_row > mcr.max_row:
                self.sheet.merged_cells.ranges.remove(mcr)
```