# How to delete columns of excel with openpyxl without changing the merged cells?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I tried to delete the first columns of the excel file in `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G6nE5wiNRf5sip22dQ8dfhuKgxzm4f8E`.

Here is my code:

```
dg = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet_obj = dg.active
sheet_obj.delete_cols(1)
dg.save('sample2.xlsx')
```

However, the position of the column names changes.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]
What is the correct approach?

Comment: That's not true. The merged cell definitions are unaffected by the deletion and can be "shifted" to the left easily.

Comment: The definitions of the merged cells are kept separately and untouched when you add or delete rows or columns. This means that you can edit them yourselves. In the screens you can actually see this as well (no border on the cell to right of status).

Comment: @CharlieClark: Thanks to clarify, e.g. the merged cells definition of `C2` got not deleted but points still to `C2`. To correct this man have only to change the definition to point now to `B2`.

Comment: Can you show me the code?

Comment: @Chan: ***"show me the code"***: I write a answer as soon as i have a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the merged cell ranges accordingly.

```py
def delete_col_with_merged_ranges(sheet, idx):
    sheet.delete_cols(idx)

    for mcr in sheet.merged_cells:
        if idx < mcr.min_col:
            mcr.shift(col_shift=-1)
        elif idx <= mcr.max_col:
            mcr.shrink(right=1)

delete_col_with_merged_ranges(sheet_obj, 1)
```

Here is an analogous function for deleting a row within a merged cell ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682506/openpyxl-in-python-delete-rows-function-breaks-the-merged-cell/54683653#54683653)):

```py
def delete_row_with_merged_ranges(sheet, idx):
    sheet.delete_rows(idx)

    for mcr in sheet.merged_cells:
        if idx < mcr.min_row:
            mcr.shift(row_shift=-1)
        elif idx <= mcr.max_row:
            mcr.shrink(bottom=1)
```